# Developing for legacy Windows Mobile OS under Windows 10

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-10

I was about to migrate to Windows 10 when I got a message saying that Windows Mobile Device Center app would be removed. This got me cancelling the whole thing, as I still need it (or at least I *think* I do need it) to debug / deploy an application on Motorola MC90XX devices, running Windows CE 5.2.

The app is written in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) for .NET CF 3.5.

I'm contemplating migrating to Windows 10 anyway and install Windows 8.1 as a virtual machine, on which I could install both WMDC and Visual Studio 2008.

Before I go ahead and take the time to do all this, I would like to know: has anybody successfully managed to setup such a working environment for development? Any caveats I should be aware of?

Comment: Odd, I heared a colleague who had the same warning, but last tuesday I went from Windows 7 to 10 and did not get the warning; plugging in the device (Motorola MC17, on CE 5) triggered that annoying green window as usual. I had to copy some .CSharp.targets files from `\Windows.old\...` to `\Windows\...` to be able to _build_ for .NET CF again though.

Comment: So what happenned? Is it possible to do Windows Mobile development on windows 10?

Comment: @Rumi Yeah I did have a few flags raising on compatibility but haven't met any issues AFA debugging and deployment goes.

Comment: @Crono Thanks. I think you should answer your own question and mark it answered so that everyone can benefit.

Comment: so what files are required in the windows directory? I didn't upgrade this PC from an older version of Windows so I don't have a windows.old to copy from...will it be possible to develop for Win CE 5.0 + 6.0 on windows 10 for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few months working with VS2008 in Windows 10 I can safely say that it is possible to develop for Windows CE 6 and prior with this setup. I haven't met any serious issues preventing me to work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Please view the answers in this thread as I had the same problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394045/windows-mobile-device-center-stops-working-after-windows-10-1703-upgrade#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394045/windows-mobile-device-center-stops-working-after-windows-10-1703-upgrade#_=_)

TLDR:
*"After install, you must right click on Start, and then click on Computer Management > Services & Applications > Services. Scroll down to right-click on "Windows Mobile-2003-based device connectivity" to select Properties > Log On. Switch to "Local System account" with checking "Allow service to interact with desktop" then click OK.

On the handheld, tap on Start > Settings > Connections > USB to PC icon, uncheck the “Enable Advanced Network Functionality” checkbox, tap OK, and then connect the cable."*