# Windows Mobile Device center stops working after Windows 10 1703 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-ce

i just installed new Windows 10 version (1703) and now i'm not able to connect any Windows CE device because Windows Mobile Device center 6.1 doesn't run.

I tried to reinstall it but there is no way, the install process stops.
Do i have to downgrade to a previous version of Windows? 
Is there a workaround for this situation?

Thanks for your advices
regards

Comment: I found this solution, and seems work. Hope this help you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9cab3e8e-6cc4-48e4-8ed9-d595bc83f04b/windows-mobile-device-centre?forum=win10itproapps

Comment: I think this broke again with a recent (September 2017) update. All the steps below which used to work, don't anymore.  Will be interesting to see if this post starts getting more attention in the upcoming days\weeks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

UPDATE: Some good suggestions which seem to work are now at this web page.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9cab3e8e-6cc4-48e4-8ed9-d595bc83f04b/windows-mobile-device-centre

PREVIOUS: I am able to get Windows Mobile Device Center (WMDC) to install, but not fully run. Installing required manually enabling the .NET Framework 3.5 similar to as described at the following web page.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-instal-net-framework-35-on-windows-10/450b3ba6-4d19-45ae-840e-78519f36d7a4

After install, you must right click on Start, and then click on Computer Management > Services & Applications > Services. Scroll down to right-click on "Windows Mobile-2003-based device connectivity" to select Properties > Log On. Switch to "Local System account" with checking "Allow service to interact with desktop" then click OK.

On the handheld, tap on Start > Settings > Connections > USB to PC icon, uncheck the “Enable Advanced Network Functionality” checkbox, tap OK, and then connect the cable.

WMDC never shows connected, but ActiveSync on the handheld does, and you can at least open File Explorer on your PC to “browse the contents of the remote device” for transferring files. I am not sure how much this limits RAPI functions.

These Services settings changes must also be re-applied every time you Restart your PC. So this is obviously not a final solution.

Comment: Both changes helped: Switch to ```Local System account``` with checking ```Allow service to interact with desktop```

Comment: +1 -> I just had this problem and I performed the steps on the "Computer Management" side and now it worked. Thank you, Orion!

Comment: The first link also works for Windows 10 version 1803. So it's still relevant!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.

I just did the following because I had 3.5 net framework :

Click right click on Start, and then click on Computer Management > Services & Applications > Services. Scroll down to right-click on "Windows Mobile-2003-based device connectivity" to select Properties > Log On. Switch to "Local System account" with checking "Allow service to interact with desktop" then click OK.
Restart my computer and it actually works again.

Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

Try this

Open the command line as an administrator and run these two commands:

```bash
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RapiMgr /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WcesComm /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

After that, reboot your PC/laptop and the Windows Mobile device center should work again.

Comment: This is the solution for Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps

- Go To Services
- Find Windows Mobile-2003-based device connectivity (Something like that)
- Select Properties
- Log On
- Log On As
- Select: Local System Account
- Go back to General Tab
- Select Startup Type: Manual
- Click Start
- Click Ok

Answer (score 0):

[Support Note, 2 June 2017](http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-849325/Sprtnote_WMDC_WindowsConnectionIssues_0617.pdf)

This worked for me, although not quite perfectly. When I disconnect my device the Device Center should stay up and show Disconnected, but instead it shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone.

Trying to connect VS2008 to WM6.1 device for a legacy project. I have been successful connecting to a WinCE device with just the registry update.

I made the changes as above, the registry updates, services logon to local and interact with desktop. Still couldn't get it to work.

Finally, I disabled the AVG advanced firewall and left the Windows firewall settings as they were and it worked. The firewall is set up so that any apps requiring access through them should cause popups but they didn't.

Can't see anyway to customize the AVG advanced firewall so will leave it off, at least while developing.

Thanks for everyone's help.